# What does inverse_of do? What SQL does it generate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to get my head around `inverse_of` and I do not get it.

What does the generated sql look like, if any?

Does the `inverse_of` option exhibit the same behavior if used with `:has_many`, `:belongs_to`, and `:has_many_and_belongs_to`?

Sorry if this is such a basic question.

I saw this example:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cards, :inverse_of => :player
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player, :inverse_of => :cards
end
```

Answer (score 179, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), it seems like the `:inverse_of` option is a method for avoiding SQL queries, not generating them. It's a hint to ActiveRecord to use already loaded data instead of fetching it again through a relationship.

Their example:

```
class Dungeon < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :traps, :inverse_of => :dungeon
  has_one :evil_wizard, :inverse_of => :dungeon
end

class Trap < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dungeon, :inverse_of => :traps
end

class EvilWizard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dungeon, :inverse_of => :evil_wizard
end
```

In this case, calling `dungeon.traps.first.dungeon` should return the original `dungeon` object instead of loading a new one as would be the case by default.

Comment: Do you understand the comment in the documentation: "for belongs_to associations has_many inverse associations are ignored.". And yet the doc uses that exact example. What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. `inverse_of` hasn't really seen a lot of use so it might be a behaviour that's not very well defined. I've tried using it after you pointed out that feature and it hasn't really done anything useful for me.

Comment: This is all very strange to me, because it seems to me that you would always want this behavior by default, and only need to use :inverse_of when the association name can't be inferred. Also the inconsistencies in the definition are bothersome, but it has helped me out in a few cases. Any reason I shouldn't just stick it everywhere?

Comment: @Ibrahim Check this out, it was merged 23 days ago! https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9522

Comment: It makes sense for the inverse of a belongs_to association to be ignored because the child of a record A's parent record is not guaranteed to be record A -- it could be a sibling of Record A. The parent of a child of record A, however, is guaranteed to be record A.

Comment: Future reader might get help from this [blog](http://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations)... :D

Comment: As of version 4.1, Rails will try to automatically set the `:inverse_of` option for you ([pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/10886)). [...]Obviously, this falls apart when the names do not match up. [...]In that case, :inverse_of has to be explicitly set to the correct names, so it's still worth knowing how :inverse_of works. Source: https://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations

Answer (score 69):

I think `:inverse_of` is most useful when you are working with associations that have not yet been persisted.  E.g.:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, :inverse_of=>:project
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project, :inverse_of=>:tasks
end
```

Now, in the console:

```
irb> p = Project.new
=> #<Project id: nil, name: nil, ...>
irb> t = p.tasks.build
=> #<Task id: nil, project_id: nil, ...>
irb> t.project
=> #<Project id: nil, name: nil, ...>
```

Without the `:inverse_of` arguments, `t.project` would return `nil`, because it triggers an sql query and the data isn't stored yet.  With the `:inverse_of` arguments, the data is retrieved from memory.

Comment: I had a problem with accepts_nested_attributes_for. By default, only nested attributes for existing associated objects shows (edit action).

If, for example, you'd like to CREATE an object with, say, 3 associated objects, you should have Model.new (new action) and :inverse_of in your models.

Comment: Agreed on the behavior in Rails 4 and later, but it worked just fine in v3 (except some later incarnations, though the old syntax works again in v3.2.13).  And note in the join-model, cannot validate presence of the id's any more - only the model-object.  Seems you can have an association without an id for it, in v4 'logic'.

Comment: Exactly.. `:inverse_of` solved an issue for me when creating new parent and child entities in the same form.

Answer (score 30):

After this pr (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9522) **inverse_of** is not required in most cases.

Active Record supports automatic identification for most associations with standard names. However, Active Record will not automatically identify bi-directional associations that contain a scope or any of the following options:

- :through
- :foreign_key

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, inverse_of: 'writer'
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :writer, class_name: 'Author', foreign_key: 'author_id'
end

a = Author.first
b = a.books.first
a.first_name == b.writer.first_name # => true
a.first_name = 'David'
a.first_name == b.writer.first_name # => true
```

In the above example, a reference to the same object is stored in the variable `a` and in the attribute `writer`.

Comment: I'm using Rails 5, and either you add `inverse_of` or not, the result for `a.first_name == b.author.first_name` is always ture.

Comment: @ArslanAli thanks for the great comment, I updated the answer.

Comment: @Arslan Ali I think it is about firing a sql query on not. It is not about if they equal or not.

Answer (score 8):

Just an update for everyone - we just used `inverse_of` with one of our apps with a `has_many :through` association

---

It basically makes the "origin" object available to the "child" object

So if you're using the Rails' example:

```
class Dungeon < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :traps, :inverse_of => :dungeon
  has_one :evil_wizard, :inverse_of => :dungeon
end

class Trap < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dungeon, :inverse_of => :traps
  validates :id,
      :presence => { :message => "Dungeon ID Required", :unless => :draft? }

  private
  def draft?
      self.dungeon.draft
  end 
end

class EvilWizard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dungeon, :inverse_of => :evil_wizard
end
```

Using `:inverse_of` will allow you to access the data object that it's the inverse of, without performing any further SQL queries

Answer (score 6):

When we have 2 models with has_many and belongs_to relationship, it's always better to use inverse_of which inform ActiveRecod that they belongs to the same side of the association. So if a query from one side is triggered, it will cache and serve from cache if it get triggered from the opposite direction. Which improves in performance. From Rails 4.1, inverse_of will be set automatically, if we uses foreign_key or changes in class name we need to set explicitly.

Best article for details and example.

http://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `has_many_through` relation between two models, User and Role, and want to validate the connecting model Assignment against non existing or invalid entries with `validates_presence of :user_id, :role_id`, it is useful. You can still generate a User @user with his association `@user.role(params[:role_id])` so that saving the user would not result in a failing validation of the Assignment model.

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look 2 two useful resources

- https://www.viget.com/articles/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Bi-directional+associations

And remember some limitations of `inverse_of` :

> does not work with :through associations.
>
> does not work with :polymorphic associations.
>
> for belongs_to associations has_many inverse associations are ignored.