# association failing in Rails 3.2 ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've got Buildings, Apartments, Residences and Users that for some reason aren't playing well together.  Not sure what I'm missing.

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ...

  has_many :apartments, inverse_of: :building
  ...
end


class Apartments < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :building, inverse_of: :apartment
  has_many :residences, inverse_of: :apartment
  ...
end


class Residence < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :apartment, inverse_of: :residence
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :residence
  ...
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  has_many :residences, inverse_of: :user
...
end
```

In the rails console I have problems with inverse associations:

> a.class

=> Apartment(id: integer, building_id: integer, ..., created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

> a.building

ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the inverse association for building (:apartment in Building)
from /Users/[me]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@r3t2/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:246:in `check_validity_of_inverse!'

> h.class

=> Residence(id: integer, apartment_id: integer, user_id: integer..., created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

> h.user

ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the inverse association for user (:residence in User)
from /Users/[me]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@r3t2/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:246:in `check_validity_of_inverse!'

I could go on.  The relationship between these classes seem to be getting hung up on inverse.  I've tried various iterations over the last couple of hours but am finally calling "ma ma!"  Would be super grateful for any leads.

Comment: Why even use `:inverse_of`?  Rails will determine the inverse relationships for your case where the `:belongs_to` and `:has_many` declarations have names that match their classes.

Comment: Hmmm... I thought I had tried these associations without the inverse and got the same errors but it seems to be working now. Thanks, @GoZoner!  Put your comment in an answer and I'll select it if you think my pitiful question is worth the effort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why even use :inverse_of? Rails will determine the inverse relationships for your case where the :belongs_to and :has_many declarations have names that match their classes.

Comment: Where is it documented? The [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Bi-directional+associations) says "By default, Active Record doesn’t know anything about these inverse relationships"

Comment: Please read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9297745/1116374 it have an answer for your question "why even use :inverse_of?"

Comment: @Skydan, did you read the second sentence?  For his case, he has no need to even use `:inverse_of` and, in fact, because he had a typo, he broke Rails computing the `:inverse_of` automagically.

Comment: @GoZoner, yes I did. Maybe you missed something, but afaik "automagically computing of `:inverse_of`" is not implemented in Rails 3.2, and since @BenU uses it, I guess he knows why.

Answer (score 7):

The apartment association in `Building` is plural, so you should add an `s`:

```
class Apartments < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :building, inverse_of: :apartments
  has_many :residences, inverse_of: :apartment
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks, @MichaëlWitrant.  That could be the solution should I need to use `inverse_of` in the future.