# ActiveAdmin nested form whit new item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, admin, activeadmin, nested-forms

I have a problem with ActiveAdmin and nested form: when I create a new question with some replies, I get an error (Question can't be blank). But if I create a question and then, on update, I add some replies everything goes well.

Can anyone help me?

Here my codes

```
# models/question.rb
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :points, :text, :replies_attributes
# RELATIONS
  has_many :replies

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :replies
end

# models/reply.rb
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :correct, :question_id, :text, :question
# VALIDATIONS
  validates_presence_of :text, :question_id
# RELATIONS
  belongs_to :question
end

# admin/question.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Question do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
      f.input :text
      f.input :points
    end
    f.inputs do
      f.has_many :replies do |rp|
        rp.input :text
        rp.input :correct
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Comment: it's not a good solution but if i remove the validation on question_id all goes well

Comment: got an answer?. i am facing the same issue

Comment: added an issue here https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3876

Comment: @svarione, try 
has_many :replies, inverse_of :question

Answer (score 0):

...maybe :inverse_of can help you.

[What does inverse_of do? What SQL does it generate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296694/what-does-inverse-of-do-what-sql-does-it-generate)