# Checking Expense amount and expense type maximum cap

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a small expense tracking app using Rails 4.1. There is an expense_types model with expense_name and cap. This is used to set maximum caps for Gas, Mobile etc. claims. Expense types belong to the expenses model that users submit. In the new expense form, they get to pick the expense type from a drop down and add line items.

I use a model method to calculate the total of all line items. Now, I'd like to check after every submission if the total amount exceeds the expense type cap. The expense type is stored for each submission. For example, if a Gas (expense_type_id = 2) bill is submitted for $100 and the cap is $80 I'd like to update the notification attribute.

I'm a bit confused how to do this correctly. I tried the following method, but got the undefined method expense_type error:

```
def check_cap
    if self.expense_amount.to_i != self.expense_type.cap
        self.update_attribute(:notification, "This item is over the budget")
    end
end
```

Wondering how to use the expense_type_id properly to check the condition Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expense_type association is backwards.  Expense should belong_to expense_type, not the other way around.

Use ActiveRecord validations and errors to indicate that the amount is over the cap. This way the record will not be valid and will not save until it is valid.

Check that the expense_amount is greater than the cap. Checking that it is not equal would mark the item as over budget any time the expense amount is higher OR lower than the cap.

```
class ExpenseType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :expenses
end

class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :expense_type

  validate :expense_amount_is_within_cap

  def expense_amount_is_within_cap 
    if expense_amount > expense_type.cap
      errors.add(:expense_amount, 'is over the budget')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: those were some really useful clarifications. If you don't mind can you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357590/associating-nested-attributes-to-user and let me know how I can associate comments to users?