# ActiveRecord includes reverse direction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have a query that looks like this:

```
merge_groups_with_mems_and_fps = PersonMergeGroup.joins(:members)
    .where('merge_group_members.member_id IN (?)', member_ids)
    .includes(:members, :field_preferences)
```

And the class of the association:

```
class FieldPreference < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :merge_group
end
```

Now, when I say something like

```
merge_groups_with_mems_and_fps.first.field_preferences[0].merge_group
```

The result is a new query.

What's a good way to make sure when I call on a field_preference, and want its merge_group, I only look in merge_groups_with_mems_and_fps and don't make a new query?  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to hint to Rails about this association:

```
class FieldPreference < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :merge_group, inverse_of: :field_preference
end
```

Check out the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html). Also, related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296694/what-does-inverse-of-do-what-sql-does-it-generate).

Comment: Awesome, looks like I want the inverse_of on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call the `merge_group` association without including it in your original query. Unless you add it to the `include` section, you'll generate a new query every time you reference `merge_group` on any element in the `field_preferences` collection. You probably want something that looks like this:

```
merge_groups_with_mems_and_fps = PersonMergeGroup.joins(:members)
    .where(merge_group_members: member_ids)
    .includes(:members, field_preferences: { :merge_group })
```

PS: ActiveRecord will generate `IN` queries for you, so you can specify those conditions as hash parameters for your `where` query.

Comment: Interesting! the two merge_groups are different objects.  Thanks!