# Need clarification on has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a simple version of Amazon where Users can buy and sell products. I have two types of Users: a buyer and a seller. I also have a Product model and an Order model.

I was able to create the functionality to allow a seller to create a product in order to sell it but I am having difficulty creating the associations between the buyer, order, and product. I think the closest I have gotten so far is this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :orders

  has_many :buyers, through: :orders, foreign_key: 'buyer_id'

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :orders

  has_many :bought_products, through: :orders, foreign_key: 'product_id'

end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :buyer

  belongs_to :product

end
```

The reason why I think this is the closest is because I am able to go to the command line and do:

```
p = Product.first
p.orders.build
```

and get back:

```
#<Order:0x007fc76e575728> {
            :id => nil,
       :address => nil,
      :quantity => nil,
    :created_at => nil,
    :updated_at => nil,
      :buyer_id => nil,
    :product_id => 6
}
```

However, I have no such luck when I'm coming from the other way:

```
 u = User.first

#<User:0x007fc76e53f4e8> {
                 :id => 1,
               :name => "Herbert",
              :email => "h@gmail.com",
    :password_digest => "$2a$10$FqcGq.Z3bKcK2X0gDv9VS.pzw62bcy5ouSF73f3razmhwvJVuOVj6",
         :created_at => Tue, 22 Sep 2015 16:56:33 UTC +00:00,
         :updated_at => Tue, 22 Sep 2015 17:05:43 UTC +00:00
}

u.orders.build

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'user_id' for Order.
```

For some reason it's trying to locate the 'user_id' but I would have thought it would be looking for the 'buyer_id' instead. I don't think I have a good understanding of the relationships I am trying to create. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could break down exactly where i'm going wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, class_name: 'Order', foreign_key: :buyer_id, inverse_of: :buyer
  has_many :bought_products, through: :orders, foreign_key: 'product_id', class_name: 'Product'
end

 class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :buyer, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :orders
   belongs_to :product
 end
```

In you case bug was produced, because Rails built `Order` from given `User` having no idea that the `User` is "buyer" for the `Order`.

Also `bought_products` declaration from your code needs to explicitly define `class_name`, while Rails can't figure out that "bought products" are simply products.

Comment: Thanks for the reply dimakura. Seems like i'm getting a similar error: (pry) output error: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: orders.user_id:

Comment: Double checked everything you had suggested to change and no luck

Comment: @Banner sorry, `has_many :orders` should have longer list of options (see updated answer)

Comment: No worries. I made the recommended changes and now I am getting the following error: ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the inverse association for orders (:buyer in User)

Comment: has_many :orders, class_name: 'Order', foreign_key: :buyer_id, inverse_of: :buyer

Comment: Working now with the above code. Thanks for your help dimakura!

Comment: In case anyone needs more info on inverse_of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296694/what-does-inverse-of-do-what-sql-does-it-generate