# Cart validations for maximum items

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models, cart and line_item:

cart.rb & line_item.rb

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :cart
 belongs_to :user
```

application_controller.rb

```
def current_cart
    Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    cart = current_user.cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
    cart
end
```

How can I add validations to my cart so that user can only add 5 items maximum into their cart? At the moment I have this code but it is not working?

```
def maximum_items_not_more_than_5
    if line_items.count > 5
      errors.add(:line_items, "must be less than 5")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is `line_item` belonging to `user`?? Surely it would be `item`:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :carts
end

#app/models/cart.rb
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user

   has_many :line_items, inverse_of: :cart
   has_many :items, through: :line_items

   validate :max_line_items

   private

   def max_line_items
      errors.add(:tags, "Too many items in your cart!!!!!!") if line_items.size > 5
   end
end

#app/models/line_item.rb
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :cart, inverse_of: :line_items
   belongs_to :item #-> surely you want to specify which item is in the cart?
end

#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :line_items
   has_many :carts, through: :line_items
end
```

---

**Validation**

This is certainly in the realms of [*validation*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html), specifically a [custom method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods):

```
#app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   validate :method

   private

   def method
       ## has access to all the instance attributes
   end
end
```

I also put `inverse_of` into the mix.

You can see how this works here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20283759/1143732

Specifically, it allows you to call `parent` / `child` objects from a particular model, thus allowing you to call validations & methods residing in those files.

In your case, it *may* be prudent to add validations to the `line_item` model -- specifying individual quantities or something. You can call the validations in this model directly from your `cart` model by setting the correct `inverse_of`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way, I would try :

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :cart, validate: true # enables validation
```

Then inside the Cart model, write your own custom validation like :

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  validate :maximum_items_not_more_than_5 # using custom validation

  private

  def maximum_items_not_more_than_5
    if line_items.count > 5
      errors.add(:base, "must be less than 5")
    end
  end
```

Comment: Arup strikes again. You, sir, are making amazing progress in rails!!