# What is the purpose of inverse_of in association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I see this code but cant understand

```
class Criminal < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :prison, inverse_of: :criminals
end
class Prison < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :criminals, inverse_of: :prison
end
```

What is inverse_of doing?

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296694/what-does-inverse-of-do-what-sql-does-it-generate)  it doesn't clear to me

Comment: "what is inverse_of doing" - have you tried reading the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses)?

Comment: https://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations